# Why can't openSSL verify google's certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, debugging

When I run the command `openssl -connect www.google.com:443` from a Debian VM, I get the following within the output:

> Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)

What's going on here? I've never had a cert problem with Google, so it's gotta be something with Debian or it's openSSL library. Debugging other SSL systems is harder when tools like this don't validate systems I know work!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On another Linux distribution I use, the naked `-connect` verb doesn't actually import the root CA packages installed on the system. To get that, you need to add `-CApath /etc/ssl/wherever/`, where the path is the location of the root CA certificate bundles.

Without CAPath:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = ZA, O = Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd., CN = Thawte SGC CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=mail.google.com
   i:/C=ZA/O=Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd./CN=Thawte SGC CA
 1 s:/C=ZA/O=Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd./CN=Thawte SGC CA
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
 ---
```

With CAPath:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = Class 3 Public Primary Certification     Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = ZA, O = Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd., CN = Thawte SGC CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google Inc, CN = mail.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=mail.google.com
   i:/C=ZA/O=Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd./CN=Thawte SGC CA
 1 s:/C=ZA/O=Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd./CN=Thawte SGC CA
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
---
```